# Call of a method that returns int[]

Tags: java, class, methods, int, call

I have the following code :

```
 public int[] getState() {

    int[] a = new int[SIZE];
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) { a[i] = mCells[i].getState(); }
    return a;
}

public void setState(int player, int[] state){

    setCurrentPlayer(player);
    //state = new int[9];
    // have tried this.getState();
    state = getState();

}
```

but i get the following compiler error :

```
Your code did not compile: /testClass.java:25: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getState()
location: class testClass
state = getState();
    ^
1 error
```

I have two class **CellState** with :

```
public int getState(){
    return mState;
}
```

And **GameState** with the first **getState** and the following attribute :

```
private CellState[] mCells;
```

Can you please advice ?

Thanks a lot in advance !! :)

Comment: Please show a [minimal, *complete* example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the compilation error.

Comment: If you are calling your `getState()` in your `testClass` but it's implemented in your `CellState`, you should call it by creating an instance of `CellState`! `state = getState();` is not the proper way to do it.

Comment: Hi, i'm using an **web IDE** (its a course that i follow to learn android dev) , please check the picture in the following link [link](http://s18.postimg.org/3jmlpeyyx/issue.png)

Comment: @OmarBISTAMI How about `GameState gState = new GameState(); gState.getState();` ?

Comment: I don't have yet a constructor in the `GameState` , note that the `getState()` method is declared in the `GameState` class.

Do you think the issue is caused by **Web IDE** ? in my android studio i don't have any errors (no test class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`state = getState()` in `TestClass.java` is the same thing as state = `this.getState()`, as you say that you also tried.  That means that Java is looking for a method named `getState()` in `TestClass.java.`  Are you trying to call the `getState()` method in `CellState.java`?  If so, you need an instance of a `CellState` object to call the `getState()` method on. For example, code like this should compile in `TestClass.java`.

```
CellState myCellState = new CellState();
//do things with myCellState
myCellState.getState();
```

Comment: Hi , thanks for your answer, i'm trying to call the `GameState.getState()` who calls the `CellState.getState() `  , also i'm using a web IDE (its a course for android) , please check link : [link](http://s18.postimg.org/3jmlpeyyx/issue.png)

Comment: The same concept applies.  If you're trying to call `GameState`'s `getState()` method, then you need an instance of `GameState` to call `getState()` on.

Comment: Even if the method is declared in the class `GameState` ?

Do you think the issue is caused by **Web IDE** ? in my android studio i don't have any errors (no test class)

Comment: I'm not sure just calling that method directly is what you want, though.  It looks like `getState()` returns an `int`.  In your `setState()` method, the variable `state` is an array of `int`s.  A variable that has the type `int[]` (an array of `int`s) can't be assigned a value that is an `int`.

Comment: `public int[] getState(){
int[] a = new int[SIZE];
for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++){
a[i] = mCells[i].getState();
}
return a;
}`
my `getState()` should return an in[] right ?

Comment: (For non-static methods like you have here) methods you write in a class can only be called on an instance of that class.  You might be confused about this because you're doing things like calling `setCurrentPlayer(player)`, not `someObject.setCurrentPlayer(player)`.  That's because Java is (secretly) treating this as if you wrote `this.setCurrentPlayer(player)`: you are calling `setCurrentPlayer(player)` on an instance of `TestClass.java`.  You would probably benefit from learning some basic object-oriented Java.

Comment: Yes, if the `getState()` in `GameState.java` returns `int[]` then the variable types will match.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation, i didn't know about the java secretly treating the method `setCurrentPlayer` but i have tried my syntax in android studio and i have compiled my project no error , only in the Web IDE of the courses i follow that i get this error through the java `Testclass` as you can see : [link](http://s28.postimg.org/3n5hjvdvx/issue2.png)

Comment: Hi, i found the solution : 
`public void setState(int player, int[] state){
setCurrentPlayer(player);
for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++){
mCells[i].setState(state[i]);
}
}`  My first declaration was correct but in the Web IDE , i didn't quite understood what the lab wanted from me to implement that's why the java `TestClass` prompted an error. thanks a lot for your help !! :)

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution :

```
public void setState(int player, int[] state){ 
setCurrentPlayer(player); 

for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++){ 
   mCells[i].setState(state[i]); 
} 
}
```

My first declaration was correct but in the Web IDE , i didn't quite understood what the lab wanted from me to implement that's why the java TestClass prompted an error (the lab wanted : Description: Set the current player to player and each cell's state to the corresponding state in state.)

thanks a lot for your help guys! ( i can go to sleep now.. :) )